# Set default classpath to use in `java` command in command prompt

Tags: java, mysql, windows, command-line

What I'm trying to do is running a `.java` source by compiling and running it from command prompt (not using any IDE) using commands `javac` and `java` and the program connects with MySQL, so everytime I run the program from cmd, I need to specify path of the MySQL connector using `-classpath` switch of `java`. And entire command to run the program gets something like below:

`java -class .;path/to/connector/mysql-connector.jar MySQLConnect`

where I want it to be as simple as for other programs like `java MySQLConnect`
and it should run the program.

Is there any way I can add the connector's path to environment variables of Windows that `java` make use of it. I already tried by creating a new `CLASSPATH` variable in Windows environment variables and added absolute path of the connector with file name along, but that didn't worked.

Please provide me the workaround of this Windows and Ubuntu as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WIndows : Copy `mysql-connector.jar` to  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\ext`
and copy the same file to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0\lib\ext`

go to My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Set these paths

```
 JAVA_HOME  
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0

 PATH 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;

 CLASSPATH
 .;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0\lib\ext\mysql-connector.jar;.;
```

open a fresh command propmpt

type
     java -version press Enter

Comment: you saved my life.thk u

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I'm guessing it's a "try everything and hope that something works" sort of strategy?  Putting the connector jar in Java\jre...\lib\ext\ was what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

**WINDOWS**

Go to `My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`

then find CLASSPATH variable in System variables and click on edit to add your jar file there.

**LINUX** or **MAC**

In your shell use a variable CLASSPATH in your .bashrc or .profile to set a default class path.

Answer (score 1):

Set `classpath=%classpath%;location` of `mysql-connector` with `connector file name.jar`. For example:

```
set classpath=%classpath%;D:\TECHNICAL\JAVA WORLD\JDBC\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;
```

`D:\TECHNICAL\JAVA WORLD\JDBC\` is the location of `mysql-connector`.

To set this path go to `Advanced System Settings`->`Environment variables`->`User variables`->`CLASSPATH`->`Edit`, then type `set classpath=%classpath%;D:\TECHNICAL\JAVA WORLD\JDBC\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;` and finally press `OK`.

I have done in this style. After that, I got result of programs correctly. Then there is `noCLassNotFoundException`.

Comment: is this a new question? this does not look like an answer