# mysql jboss connectivity

Tags: mysql, jboss

I have  copied the  mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin to jboss/server/default/lib. But still i am getting the following exception.

```
   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
   /jbossdb
```

Comment: This may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946088/set-default-classpath-to-use-in-java-command-in-command-prompt/8946331#8946331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the xml files. You can find the tutorial to do this in the internet.