# Java and mysql communication

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I'm developing a web service in Java which interacts with a MySQL database. I have already developed the petition to the databse in java and the stored procedure in the Mysql... but the communication is not working. I always receive this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/madrim
```

I'm working on Windows using Tomcat server for the web services in JAVA. I downloaded the mysql driver ("mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar") and added to the folder of the tomcat (~\Tomcat 7.0\lib), but it doesn't do anything.

What could it be? Any hints?

Here a bit of code... :

```
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try 
    {           
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER_NAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        st = con.createStatement();

        String query = BuildQuery();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        returnObj.SetResult(rs);
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        returnObj.SetException(DataException.SQL);
    }
```

It crashed and goes to the catch.

EDIT: More stuff.

The context.xml of Tomcat:

```
<Context>    
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource name="jdbc/madrim" 

          auth="Container"

          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 

          username="root" 

          password="asdf"

          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/madrim"

          maxActive="15" 

          maxIdle="3"/>  

</Context>
```

And the WEB-INF/web.xml of the project:

```
<resource-ref>
<description>AccesoBaseDeDatos</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/madrim</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

Comment: It will help potential answerers if you show us the problem area of your code.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946088/set-default-classpath-to-use-in-java-command-in-command-prompt/8946331#8946331/set-default-classpath-to-use-in-java-command-in-command-prompt/8946331#8946331

Comment: @user1042031 IMO not very useful--this is a web app, and we don't know how the OP is attempting to init the driver.

Comment: Driver not found is usually jar file missing(in any case web or standalone) either OP should put Jar file in tomcat/lib (which he did )or in Class path , If there was any other error in the connection code, error would have been different.

Comment: @user1042031 I tried that answer with no success. The error continues.

Comment: Did you registered your jdbc driver with the java application? Post your connection part code

Comment: I added the java part of the connection and the configuration in tomcat...

Answer (score 0):

You should add MySQL Driver to your **build path** not just to libs folder.

If you're using Eclipse then you can easily add the driver by going to the *properties* of your project then

> Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs

If it still not working try rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just try registering the Driver using :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

It should work.

Comment: I don't understand this. Can you explain it a bit more?  Thanks

Comment: Once i had similar issue when my dev server was in tomcat6 when the prod server was in tomcat 7, Have to register the driver once again and it worked, I dont know why may be someone better than me can explain this.