# MySql Driver Not Loading In Java

Tags: java, mysql

When I use the following line,

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//Sets up database connection
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://www.papademas.net/tickets?"
        + "user=root&password=jamesp");

statement = connect.createStatement();

String sql = "INSERT INTO JReimTicketer (dateIssued, ticketName, issuerName,"
        + " issuerDepartment, ticketDescription, activity) "
        + "VALUES (SYSDATE(),'"+ticketName+"', '"+issuerName+"', "
        + "'"+issuerDepartment+"', '"+ticketDescription+"', "
        + " '"+activity+"')";
```

my program stops, and it doesn't seem like it loads the driver. I've downloaded it, so I'm not sure why it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the code *after* this? Does it throw an error? Show as a little bit more of the code you use.

Comment: Are you set a classpath for it

Comment: @TamilSelvan I don't believe so. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946088/set-default-classpath-to-use-in-java-command-in-command-prompt

Comment: Do u get any exception ? If yes, then show us.

Comment: I'm not getting any exceptions

Comment: Have u added MySQL driver jar in project build ?

Comment: Use class build path and import jar file for mysql jdbc. It can be the reason for why compiler is unable to find the class.

Comment: The mysql driver wasn't in the right file in my file system. Once I moved it, the code worked fine. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if your are using jdbc 4.0, you don't require

> Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

to load driver as it it auto-loaded when you call

> DriverManager.getConnection();

If you have specified mysql jar in your class path, the problem must be in your url. So kindly check your URL/Username/Password

Also, if you are getting exception,please post stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. And I think you're right. Things aren't missing from Front-End but Back-End. So, before you compile your code, you need to put **MySQL Connecter jar (mysql-connector-java-x.x.xxx-bin.jar)** file in your **Java Buildpath Path**. Do it before you compile and run the code.